# Angular with Yeoman 1.0 and Grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

Folks,

I am working on Win 7 professional.
Versions of various utilities on my computer are as follows:
Nodejs : v0.10.8
npm: v1.2.23

### I am trying to seed the Angular application using Yeoman. I have followed the following instructions

1. First install yo,bower and grunt
   npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower
2. Goto the directory where I want to create my webapp and run

c:\somefolder>yo angular

1. Runt the grunt server
   C:>grunt server

Steps 1 and 2 above run fine but on step 3 I get the following errors

C:\somefolder>grunt -server
Running "clean:dist" (clean) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

> > 3 files lint free.

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "coffee:dist" (coffee) task

Running "coffee:test" (coffee) task

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

---

Now I do have ruby installed and its available in PATH variable. 
C:>ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [i386-mingw32]

How do I oversome this? How do i ensure that grunt server does not abort ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have compass installed?

Comment: If you don't want to use compass (very likely if you know nothing about them) you can comment all lines in Gruntfile.js where is mentioned to disable them.

Answer (score 3):

> gem install compass

also here:

https://rubygems.org/gems/compass

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you mentioned and I noticed that Compass had to be called as compass2.0 so I symlinked compass to compass2.0 and it solved the problem.

Here's the command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/compass2.0 /usr/bin/compass
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on OS X. Here is the series of commands I eventually used to get everything installed and working: https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/f1d7e4d1c31ae3b0899e

FWIW, it seems like the missing piece for me was `gem install sass`. In theory, `gem install compass` should have installed Sass too, but explicitly installing Sass made the error disappear.