# Ruby and compass path with yeoman project

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass, yeoman

I installed ruby, yeoman, and when I run my project, I have this error:

> Warning: Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
>   Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed
>    this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gru
>   Use --force to continue. Use --force to continue.

I have the path into the variable session target, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hey Jesus, mind choosing an answer?

Answer (score 12):

I had to run this:

```
gem install compass
```

Found here: [Angular with Yeoman 1.0 and Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947403/angular-with-yeoman-1-0-and-grunt)

(I thought I had Compass installed by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) but it wasn't sufficient.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from compass being called compass2.0

I solved the issue by symlinking compass to compass2.0

Here's the command: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/compass2.0 /usr/bin/compass

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.  Turns out it was masking the real error:

```
{ '0': [Error: Error: not found: bundle],
  '1': 
   { stdout: '',
     stderr: 'Error: not found: bundle',
     code: 127,
     toString: [Function] },
  '2': 127 }
```

Fixed with:

```
sudo gem install bundle --no-user-install
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on Windows 7 too..
This is what I did.

1. Install Ruby with Ruby installer
2. Install the Compass with gem, (Installing the compass with npm didnt have any effect)

   gem install compass